# Suggest encoding which removes slashes which I can use as the format for REST-style URL-paramteters

Tags: .net, php, rest, encoding, decoding

Given a path to a REST style URL:

```
http://site.com/rest/customer/foo/robot/bar/1
```

When you GET it, it returns a PDF to the *foo*-customer containing page *1* of the *bar*-URL.

While foo is the name of the customer bar is an URL. The URL usually contains slashes and might look something like this:

```
http://anothersite.com/interestingarticle.html
```

As REST URL's separate arguments by slashes I can't just put it into the REST URL above. Which encoding should I use? I can't use Base 64 as it utilizes the slash as well.

As a technical note I will encode the URL in a .NET-application and decode it in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By double URL-encoding the URL it will never contain any slashes and may therefore use parameters separated by slashes.

The URL is encoded and sent from .NET using C#:

```
String url = "http://urltoencode.com/a/page";
System.Text.Encoding westernEuropeanISOencoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
String doubleEncodedUrl = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url, westernEuropeanISOencoding);
doubleEncodedUrl = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(doubleEncodedUrl, westernEuropeanISOencoding);
```

The receiving PHP-script double decodes the URL:

```
url = decode(decode($receivedDoubleEncodedUrl));
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your use case exactly? Why does bar need to be a URL? The server can construct the URIs any way it wants to.

If you for some reason MUST use the URL, do this:

> http://site.com/rest/customer/foo/robot?bar=http://anothersite.com/interestingarticle.html&page=1

(with urlencoded query string of course).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My use case isn't creating PDF's. But I *must* send an URL through REST so the example is valid. Your way doesn't allow for additional arguments to further drill down into the URL. And it doesn't conform to the REST style of creating URL's.

Comment: Why are you saying that my way does not allow additional args? BTW: There is no such thing as a "REST style for creating URLs". The URL I show is just a perfectly valid URL (except for the not shown url encoding of the QS of course).

Comment: I thought the URL's should be created so that more paramters can be appended to drill down further into the selection. Maybe that is not the case. Using that style I won't be able to add more parameters after the URL, which is what I want to do. Using some kind of encoding.

Comment: You can append any number of query parameters to my example URI. E.g. you can append &a=1&b=2. If you need to make use of the URI path hierarchy, you can use matrix parameters but your example does not look as if you need that. Matrix parameters take the form /foo/a=1;b=2/bar/... and have the property of not 'stopping' the hierarchy. IOW, you can use path segments after the parameters to indicate further drill down.

Comment: Yes I guess your method is a possibility. However I'm pretty set on using parameters separated by slashes. It's how I've seen all REST example.